# Dev-C++ не компилирует ни один проект

Tags: devc++

Здравствуйте! Установил Dev-C++ со всеми настройками и с компилятором по умолчанию. Компилятор - MinGW. Пытаюсь запустить простейший проект наподобие HelloWorld'а:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

выдает следующую ошибку:

```
[Linker error] undefined reference to `__dyn_tls_init_callback' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `__cpu_features_init' 
ld returned 1 exit status 
C:\Dev-Cpp\Makefile.win [Build Error]  [Проект1.exe] Error 1
```

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста!

Comment: А просто g++ hello.c из консоли работает?

    #include <stdio.h>
    int main () { return puts("Hi") == EOF; }

Comment: В общем оказалось что был уже установлен в корень диска C mingw, а dev-cpp шел со своим компилятором, ну и на одном форуме было высказано предположение, что они каким-то образом мешают друг другу... В общем способа жестко задать ему нужный компилятор я что-то как-то не нашел, поэтому просто переименовал папку с ранее установленным mingw в корне диска, ну и все заработало как ни странно. =)

Answer (score 1):

Очень все просто: [Решение](http://ashishcplusplus.blogspot.in/2012/05/undefined-reference-to.html)

Comment: Пробовал, не помогло